# Suspend Linux (Mint) with external hard drive plugged in

Tags: linux-mint, hardware, suspend

I simply try to suspend the session while my external hard drive is plugged in (doesn't matter whether I have mounted or dismounted it, and this error does not apply to other filesystems, like flash drives). The computer does not suspend the session, and it goes back to the login screen, as if I had locked the screen. When I access the shell (and doing an ALT+LEFT after the CTRL+ALT+F1), I can see the following:

```
[ 5602.723820] dpm_run_callback(): scsi_bus_suspend+0x0/0x200 returns -5
[ 5602.723828] PM: Device 2:0:0:0 failed to suspend async: error -5
[ 5602.723820] PM: Some devices failed to suspend
```

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks.